# Python3 - Remove last (n) lines from file and append new data

Tags: linux, python-3.x, file-io, append, text-formatting

I have a little python script that I'm working on that will add the local weather conditions and some network information to my .bashrc file. Everything works as expected except for two bugs: first instead of removing the old data and appending the new it just appends the new data like this:

> ('echo [Local weather]:', 66.9, 'F', 'with', 'overcast clouds')
>   ('echo [Your public IP is]:', 'x.x.x.x'('echo [Local weather]:', 66.9, 'F', 'with', 'overcast clouds')
>   ('echo [Your public IP is]:', 'x.x.x.x')

and second I need to drop the formatting from the printed text, eg (parentheses, commas, etc..) so that the string appears as such:

> echo [Local weather]: 66.9F with overcast clouds
>   echo [Public IP]: x.x.x.x

Here is the file operations portion of my script:

```
    with open('HOME/.bashrc', 'a') as f:
        w = "echo [Local weather]:", wx_t,"F", "with", wx_c
        i = "echo [Your public IP is]:", ip
        out = [str(w), str(i)]
        f.write('\n'.join(out)[0:-3])
```

so I thought that `f.write('\n'.join(out)[0:-3])` would remove the last 3 lines of the file but apparently it drops the last 3 characters of the string. What do I need to change to achieve that which I attempting? Should I be using `f.writelines()` instead of `f.write()`?

The expected result will eventually look like this:

> Welcome to [hostname] You are logged in as user [some_user]
>   [Local time]: Mon Mar 20 08:28:32 CDT 2017.
>   [Local weather]: 66.56 F with clear sky
>   [Local IP]: 192.168.x.x [Public IP]: x.x.x.x

Thanks in advance and if this is a duplicate question I apologize. I felt I've done my due-diligence in searching for a solution but I have been unsuccessful.

UPDATE:
So i fixed the formatting by changing

`w = "echo [Local weather]:", wx_t,"F", "with", wx_c`

to

`w = "echo [Local weather]: " + str(wx_t) + " F, with " + wx_c`

and using `f.writelines()` instead of `f.write()`. Also I removed f.close() as suggested by DeepSpace

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to call `f.close()` since you are using `with`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still pretty new to python and wasn't sure so figured I would play it safe

Answer (score 0):

The first bug is caused by using `'a'` instead of `'w'` in the first line. This cause Python to add to the file rather than overwrite the file.

The second bug is caused because you are joining all your data into a string, and getting `[0:-3]` of the joined string, rather than `[0:-3]` of the list `out`.

Your code, fixed, should look like this:

```
with open('HOME/.bashrc', 'w') as f:
        w = "echo [Local weather]:", wx_t,"F", "with", wx_c
        i = "echo [Your public IP is]:", ip
        out = [str(w), str(i)]
        f.write('\n'.join(out[0:-3]))
```